# Visual Studio 2017 Communnity Incorrectly Updates Roslyn Scripting

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

I am using Roslyn for application scripting via Nuget Package Manager. Setup should be rather simple. Create new project and, in Nuget manager, add *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Sripting* package. After couple of confirmations you are ready to go. 
Next step should be checking for installed packages update. Currently, there are 5 updates that are shown after initial installation. Again, it is pretty straightforward to do this.

However, immediately after the update, two of those packages show yellow triangle in Reference node of the project. 
I have tried to resolve this following SO and other hints but nothing helped me so far.

At the end, I have installed new VM with Windows 10 Pro (with all updates) and VS2017 Community Edition. After that new Windows Forms project (.net 4.6.1. based for x64) was created and scripting package is added. Unfortunately, yellow triangles are still there (after update).

Problematic packages are *System.ValueTuple* and *System.Security.Cryptography. X509Certificates*.

Also, after cleaning and rebuilding the solution, a number of warnings (MSB3836) - *explicit binding redirect on "System..." conflicts with autogenerated binding redirect*.

Solution to this problem might shed a light on problem with more complex solution that I stumbled upon after migration to VS 2017.

So, what is the reason for such behavior? Remember, this happens on new installation of OS and VS with simplest project possible.

Comment: I repeat all this with Visual Studio 2015 and everything was fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2017 Communnity Incorrectly Updates Roslyn Scripting

I got the same result with you steps. This issue only occurred on the Visual Studio 2017 not Visual Studio 2015. That should have some issue with package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`.

To resolve this issue, I would like provide you a **workaround**:

**Update packages "`System.ValueTuple`" and "`System.Security.Cryptography. X509Certificates`" first, then update other packages.**

It works fine on my side, you can check if it works for you.

In order to track this issue, I have create a new issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22290

If you have additional information to add, you can add comments below that issue. And you can check the feedback from this link.

Comment: I can confirm that these steps do not produce yellow triangles. However, after rebuilding the solution I am receiving several messages like:

_Consider app.config remapping of assembly_ and _warning MSB3836: The explicit binding redirect_. 

And all this on simplest project which is not using scripting. In VS 2015 nothing similar happens. Therefore, I will have to stick with it for the time being.

Comment: After testing with more complex solution built with VS 2017 that is using scripting I did not have any problems. However, we should have in mind that this is basic testing only. For the time being this can be accepted as answer regardless of the fact that it is workaround.